# How to export a shell variable to all sessions?

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to know is there a way to export my shell variable to all sessions in the system (not only the current session). I'm not looking to set it in .bashrc file as the shell variable is a dynamic one it changes time to time.

Answer (score 13):

You can set up your sessions to keep rereading a file on disk by setting a trap on DEBUG in your `.bashrc`:

```
trap 'source ~/.myvars' DEBUG
```

If you leave a terminal A open, run `echo VAR=42 >> ~/.myvars` in terminal B, then switch back to terminal A and `echo $VAR`, it'll "magically" be set.

Comment: A creative solution. Though you do probably want to remember to remove it after it's propagated where you want it, or it will lock that variable to that value.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to misunderstand what `export` does.  All it does is to move a local variable into the environment block within the process (`/proc/$$/environ`).

When a new process is created (a `fork`) then the program data areas, including the environment block, are copied to the new process (actually they are initially shared, then copied when one writes).  When a different *program* is run (execve), by default the environment block remains from the previous program.  See also the `env(1)` program.

So environment variables are normally inherited (copied) from their parent process.  The only way to get a new environmnt variable into a running process is to use some sort of inoculation technique, as a debugger would do.  Writing such a program is not an easy task, and I'm sure you could imagine the security implications.

Comment: The `environ` entry in `/proc` only reflects the environment the process had when it began, and does not update as new environment variables are added/changed.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. A better explanation can be found in the unix stackexchange section [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8342/export-an-env-variable-to-be-available-at-all-sub-shells-and-possible-to-be-mod)!

A shell variable probably is not suited for the use you are trying to achieve. Maybe you want to use files instead.